# SciLab Plotting

Tags: function, matlab, graph, graphing, scilab

How would you plot these in SciLab or MatLab? I am new to these and have no idea how the software works. Please help.

```
$Plot following functions with different colors in Scilab or MatLab
–   f2(x) = logn
–   f3(x) = n
–   f4(x) = nlogn
–   f5(x) = n2
–   f6(x) = nj (j > 2)
–   f7(x) = cn (c > 1)
–   f8(x) = n!

where x = linspace(1, 50, 50).
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, a lot of these are built-in functions. For example

```
>> x = linspace(1,50,50);
>> plot(x,log(x))
>> plot(x,x)
>> plot(x,x.*log(x))
>> plot(x,x.^2)
```

I don't know what `nj (j > 2)` and `cn (c > 1)` are supposed to mean.

For the last one, you should look at the function `factorial`.

It's not clear from the context whether you're supposed to plot them on different graphs or all on the same graph. If all on the same graph, then you can use

```
>> hold on;
```

to freeze the current axes - that means that any new lines will get drawn on top of the old ones, instead of being drawn on a fresh set of axes.

In Matlab (and probably in Scilab) you can supply a "line spec" argument to the `plot` function, which tells it what color and style to draw the line in. For example,

```
>> figure
>> hold on
>> plot(x,log(x),'b')
>> plot(x,x/10,'r')
>> plot(x,x.^2/1000,'g')
```

Tells Matlab to plot the function `f(x)=log(x)` in blue, `f(x)=x/10` in red and `f(x)=x^2/1000` in green, which results in this plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment or upvote yet but I'd add to Chris Taylor's answer that in Scilab the `hold on` and `hold off` convention isn't used. All plot commands output to the current axes, which are 'held on' all the time. If you want to generate a new figure or change the current axes you can use `figure(n)`, where `n` can be any (nonconsecutive) positive integer - just a label really.

See also `clf(n)`, `gcf()` and `gca()` - Scilab's figure handling differs quite a bit from Matlab's, though the matplotlib ATOMS module goes some way towards making Scilab look and behave more like Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

In Scilab, it will be

```
x = 1:50;
clf
plot("ll", x,log, x,x, x,x.*log(x), x,x.^2)
gca().sub_ticks(2) = 8;
xgrid(color("grey"))
legend("$"+["ln(x)", "x", "x.ln(x)", "x^2"]+"$", "in_upper_left")
```

[image]